# How many non-empty subsets of $1,2,3,\cdots,p-2,p-1$ have a sum which is divisible by $p$ that $p$ is an odd prime?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisibility

I have to do a IMO training homework but there is a question that confusing me.

> How many non-empty subsets of $1,2,3,\cdots,p-2,p-1$ have a sum which is divisible by $p$ that $p$ is an odd prime?

I have tried $p=3,5,7$ and the number of subsets is $1,3,9$ respectively. I have thought of if the answer is $3^\frac{p-3}{2}$, but I am pretty not sure. If anyone knows the answer or find the number of subsets when $p$ is other odd primes, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: I would consider $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(1+\zeta^k)$ where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/p)$.

Comment: For $p=11,13,17,19$ the number of subsets is $93,315,3855,13797$ respectively.

Comment: Plugging Daniel Mathias's numbers into OEIS I found the [Fermat quotients](http://oeis.org/A007663).

Comment: The formula for the Fermat quotients, $\frac{2^{p-1}-1}{p}$ shows that if we can prove that the number of nonempty subsets of $[p-1]$ whose sum is $\equiv k\pmod{p}$ is the same for $k=0,1,2,\dots p-1$ then the answer is indeed given by the Fermat quotient.  Experiment  shows that this is true for odd primes up through $23$, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: I think the answer should be the answer of @saulspatz. As this homework is about number theory

Comment: If a sum is not zero mod $p$, then multiplying every term in the sum by $1,2,\dots,p-2,p-1$ in turn will run through all the nonzero residues, once each. So all the nonzero residues come up the same number of times.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should uncheck my answer, so that I can delete it.

Comment: I found your question, Issac Yiu!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider, instead, subsets of $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$. There will be twice as many subsets; and twice as many whose sum is a multiple of $p$ because you have the option of including $0$ in any subset.
Take any subset except the empty set and the full set.  Call it $S_0=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$.  Note that $1\le k\le p-1$.  There are $p$ sets $S_i=\{i+x_1,\ldots,i+x_k\}$ formed by adding the number $i$ to each element, as $i$ ranges from $0$ to $p-1$.  This adds $ki$ to the sum, so the sums are all different $\pmod p$ because we have excluded the empty set and the full set.
So the $2^p-2$ subsets split up into $p$ equal groups.  There are $(2^p-2)/p$ that are multiples of $p$.
Add back in the empty set and full set to give $2+(2^p-2)/p$.  Pair up sets that include $0$ with sets that don't, and remove the sets that include $0$. That leaves $1+(2^{p-1}-1)/p$.  Lastly, remove the empty set to leave $(2^{p-1}-1)/p$.

Comment: That's a great elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for the sum of non-empty subsets is $P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (1+x^i)  -1 $.
We want the sum of the coefficients of the exponents which are multiples of $p$, which is given by $ \frac{1}{p} \sum_{\text{x is a pth root of unity}} P(x)$.

Let $\omega$ be a primitive $pth$ root of unity.
Consider $f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} z^j = \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} ( z - \omega^i)$.
Since $p$ is odd, $1 = f(-1) = \prod (-1 - \omega^i) = \prod (1+\omega^i)$.  This shows that $P(\omega) = 0 $.
Hence, $ \frac{1}{p} \sum P(x) = \frac{1}{p} P(1) = \frac{1}{p} ( 2^{p-1} -1). $

---

To get the observation of saulspatz that the number of subsets with sum $\equiv k \pmod{p}$ is also equal to $\frac{1}{p} ( 2^{p-1} -1)$, we want the sum of the coefficients of the exponents which are of the form $np+k$, which is given by $ \frac{1}{p} \sum_{\text{x is a pth root of unity}} x^k P(x)$.

The above shows that $ \frac{1}{p} \sum x^k P(x) = \frac{1}{p} 1^k P(1) = \frac{1}{p} ( 2^{p-1} -1). $